# SQL Query to count occurrences of each distinct value

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot-table

I have a table which contains 2 fields: *userid* and *value*. There can be multiple lines with the same *userid*. The *value* column can be one of 5 distinct values.

I want to output a summary line for each *userid*, with a count of the times each distinct *value* appears in the input. That is, the summary line has the following columns: *userid*, *count of value 1*, *count of value 2*, *count of value 3*, *count of value 4*, and *count of value 5*

example

1,4

1,3

2,1

3,5

4,1

5,2

output would be

1,0,0,1,1,0

2,1,0,0,0,0

3,0,0,0,0,5

4,1,0,0,0,0

5,0,1,0,0,0

Any suggestions?

Comment: If I understand your pattern, the line that is 3,0,0,0,0,5  should be  3,0,0,0,0,1.   right?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Also, your example source data shows a maximum of one occurrence for each combination.  Is that a defining characteristic of your source data, or could (for example)  the row with values 5,2  appear more than once?  If the latter is true, please add another row or two to show this possibility (and reflect it in the output).

Comment: side note - Why use crystal when you can have a query embedded in the SSIS package that would replicate what crystal would output.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

```
select userid, 
    sum(case value when 1 then [occurs] else 0 end) as countOf1,
    sum(case value when 2 then [occurs] else 0 end) as countOf2,
    sum(case value when 3 then [occurs] else 0 end) as countOf3,
    sum(case value when 4 then [occurs] else 0 end) as countOf4,
    sum(case value when 5 then [occurs] else 0 end) as countOf5
    from
(
    select userid, [value], count(*) as [occurs]
    from inputTable
    group by userid, [value]
) t
group by userid
order by userid
```

### Assumption

I gathered from your question that the same input row values may appear multiple times, although your example data doesn't show that possibility. However, if each distinct row can only appear once, then a significantly simpler/shorter solution is available.

### Caveat

You stated that the [value] column in input can be one of 5 distinct values. My solution is based on that "requirement."  It includes one line of code for every distinct value.  However, if the number of distinct values can grow over time OR is unbounded, then a different approach using dynamic SQL would be required.